# win32api's GetSystemMetrics doesn't work in python

Tags: python, pywin32

I am making an app in customtkinter and I ran into a problem. I want the program to set it's size, so it looks good on every monitor. When I try to import win32api's GetSystemMetrics using `from win32api import GetSystemMetrics`in the output it says `Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\jakub\Desktop\customtkinter\main.py", line 2, in <module> from win32 import GetSystemMetrics ImportError: cannot import name 'GetSystemMetrics' from 'win32' (unknown location)`.

I already downloaded the newest win32api using `pip install pywin32`. It hit me with downloading which means I didn't download it. So I was happy until I opened VSCode to be greeted with the same error. If anyone knows why, please tell me. Thank you!

Comment: The error message indicates that you're trying to import from `win32`, rather than `win32api`.